# How to use currentCultureName in place of currentUICultureName for locale files spfx

Tags: spfx, language, string

We have a site with variations in SP2016, the display language is in "es-es" but the variation language is "en-us".

We add a webpart of spfx with locale resources for translate constants texts, and this text are displayed in "es-es" but we need it in "en-us".

I was reading the Microsoft documentation where they explain that spfx use the currentUICultureName of the pageContextInfo, but we need to use the currentCultureName, in place of have the correct translates.

There is any way to reach this objetive?